# How can I random sort lines in a buffer?

Tags: sorting, emacs

I have a buffer of words and phrases in sorted order and I would like to have the lines sorted in a random order.  How would I do this with either an emacs builtin function or with elisp?

For example, given

```
bar
elisp
emacs
foo
hello world
the quick brown fox
```

I would like some completely random result like:

```
foo
the quick brown fox
hello world
elisp
emacs
bar
```

or ...

```
hello world
elisp
bar
the quick brown fox
foo
emacs
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[randomize-region.el](http://www.mail-archive.com/gnu-emacs-sources@gnu.org/msg00034.html) seems to do what you want.

Comment: @Geremia: Easiest approach is probably just to cut&paste the code into your .emacs file.

Answer (score 26):

## Using Bash on GNU/Linux:

Similar to Sean's solution, select the region and then:

```
C-u M-| shuf
```

## Explanation:

M-| pipes the content of selected region to the bash command shuf. shuf shuffles the lines. The prefix C-u takes the output of shuf and uses it to overwrite the selected region.

Comment: you can use `sort -R` instead of `shuf` on many systems (linux, all BSDs except NetBSD).

Comment: Fastest and easiest!

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively, here is `sort-lines` adapted to this requirement.

I've removed the `reverse` argument (obviously not relevant here), and simply supplied a 'comparison' function returning a random result to `sort-subr`.

```
(defun my-random-sort-lines (beg end)
  "Sort lines in region randomly."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region beg end)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (let ;; To make `end-of-line' and etc. to ignore fields.
          ((inhibit-field-text-motion t))
        (sort-subr nil 'forward-line 'end-of-line nil nil
                   (lambda (s1 s2) (eq (random 2) 0)))))))
```

For the original:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `sort-lines` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind shelling out to Perl, you can select the region you want to randomize, and then type <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>M-|</kbd> `perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'print shuffle <STDIN>'`.

I'm sure many other popular programming languages offer similar facilities.